# Локализация JSON файла в iOS приложении

Tags: ios, json, локализация

В ios приложении есть json файл, в котором информация на английском языке (текст), и эта информация выводится на экраны в приложении. Как сделать, что бы отображалась информация из аналогичного json файла , только с информацией на русском языке, если в настройках iphone выбран русский язык. 
На Android это делается просто - json на английском в res/raw, на русском в res/raw-ru. В xcode не могу понять как это сделать.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310487/iphone-ios-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-localized-strings-in-all-the-languages-my-ap

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял, вам следует использовать NSLocalizedString. По ссылке ниже вы можете найти описание данного процесса.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Answer (score 1):

Если NSLocalizedString по каким-то причинам не подходит или не хочется менять json, то можно взять текущий язык и нужный файл для него:

NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
if( [language rangeOfString: @"ru"].location != NSNotFound )
    [self loadRuJson];